# Livecharts showing "-100000000000000 μ" instead of -100 M in a StackedColumnSeries

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-5, livecharts

When a value of `-1e8` is added to a StackedColumnSeries in a SKCartesianChart, the value is labelled with `-100000000000000 μ` instead of `-100 M` as expected.

I suspect this is a bug in the prerelease version of livecharts. I've [reported it](https://github.com/beto-rodriguez/LiveCharts2/issues/754), but thought to ask here in case anyone's seen the same problem and has a workaround.

```cs
        var chart = new SKCartesianChart
        {
            Series = new List<ISeries>
            {
                new StackedColumnSeries<decimal> {Values = new [] {1e8m}},
                new StackedColumnSeries<decimal> {Values = new [] {-1e8m}},  // -100000000000000 μ
            }
        };
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the report on Github, this is a bug, it is already fixed, and this fix fill be included in the next version of the library.

For now, you can build your own formatter in the YAxis:

```cs
var chart = new SKCartesianChart
{
  Series = new List<ISeries>
  {
    new StackedColumnSeries<decimal> {Values = new [] {1e8m}},
    new StackedColumnSeries<decimal> {Values = new [] {-1e8m}}
  },
  YAxes = new[]
  {
    new Axis
    {
      Labeler = value =>
      {
        var l = value == 0 ? 0 : (int)Math.Log10(Math.Abs(value));

        if (l >= 6)
        {
          value /= Math.Pow(10, 6);
          return value.ToString($"######0.####### M");
        }

        return value.ToString($"######0.#######");
      }
    }
  }
};
```